# How launch stats program JMP when a file is saved in a folder?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I want to use a code in PowerShell to launch JMP analysis. To begin I just want to launch the same code any time a file is saved in the folder and after I will adapt this. So I use something I see on this forum to create this code:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\GROUSD01\Desktop\test"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.xlsx"
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { Start-Process jmp.exe "C:\Users\GROUSD01\Desktop\Création code MPPT\ScriptMPPT.jsl"
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
```

When I run it in Powershell, it detects the new file and tries to run the command but doesn't find the file `.jsl` and JMP prints an error. But when I run this code in the command line:

```
jmp.exe "C:\Users\GROUSD01\Desktop\Création code MPPT\ScriptMPPT.jsl"`
```

It finds the good file and runs the good things.

Do you have any idea about why is there a problem?

Comment: What did you try else to debug the issue?

Comment: I try to make it with the file save in JMP or not. I try to change the path. But I don't know anything in powershell code I'm a beginner. In fact I will try something know. Maybe PowerShell doesn't support space in path I think there is no other difference with the code I found. I ask here to verify that I don't make mistake in the code. If I don't, it is file issue

Comment: That's a good idea, start with a simple action like printing a string literal or the contents of the current directory as action.